# How to test expected recs have been added to dbset mock

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, moq

I'm using Moq with EF6.

In the following code, I create a mock for a 3 DbContext objects and a config manager, all of which are passed to the constructor for *HomeController* .

```
Mock<BAMContext> bamDbContext = new Mock<BAMContext>();
        Mock<ESBContext> esbDbContext = new Mock<ESBContext>();
        Mock<UserPrefsContext> userPrefsDbContext = MockUserPrefsContext.GetContext(interchangeIds);

        var controllerContext = MockWebContext.AuthenticatedContext(adminUsers.First(), true);

        Mock<IConfigurationManager> configurationManager = new Mock<IConfigurationManager>();
        configurationManager.Setup(cm => cm.GetAppSetting("AdminUsers")).Returns(@"BizTalkBuild01\BizTalkAdmin;lgss\iwhite;");

        HomeController controller = new HomeController(bamDbContext.Object, esbDbContext.Object, userPrefsDbContext.Object, configurationManager.Object);

        controller.EnsureAdminUsersHaveDbRecs();
```

The EnsureAdminUserHaveDbRecs method will insert the required recs. It also sets a public property *UserPrefsContext* so that I reference this back in the unit test for the asserts. The inserts into the mock db context seem to work ok but if I add the following loop then the debugger does not step in:

```
foreach (var rec in controller.UserPrefsContext.UserRecs.ToList())
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(rec.AdLogonId);
        }
```

However, if I enter *? controller.UserPrefsContext.UserRecs.Count()* in the immediate window it gives a result of 3. I'm also able to print the data with e.g. *? controller.UserPrefsContext.UserRecs.First().AdLogonId*

Can anyone please explain why I can't iterate over these 3 recs?

Comment: Might be that you're compiling in Release profile?

Comment: No, it is debug